# Implementing join query using GQL in google-app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, join, gql

I have an entity kind like:

prop1 prop2  docid  other-properties

str1         p1       1001    .........

str2         p1       1002    .........

str2         p2       1001    .........

str1         p2       1003    .........

I want to have all those docid's that have "prop1 as str1 and prop2 as p1" and "prop1 as str2 and prop2 as p2" in common and want to use their other-properties. Like here the answer would be docid 1001. Can anyone suggest me a method to do so? I am even ready to change my database structure if required but I want these thing to be done by a single query only...

Ok its fine about other properties I may not need to use them, I just want all docid's that are common.

Right now I am using something like this:

for b in db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM b"):
    for a in db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM a WHERE y=:1", b.y):
          print a.x

But this is taking of lot of time since I have a huge number of entries.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking.  Why don't you clarify the question and include some code, such as your actual model definition.  Some resources you might find helpful: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html, http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html, and http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html.

Comment: I have an entity with multiple properties like prop1, prop2 and so on... and one docid. Now I want to search all those docid's that have a combination of 'prop1 as "str1" and prop2 as "p1"' and 'prop1 as "str2" and prop2 as "p2"'.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to model this would be to have the docs themselves have a list of strings:

```
class Doc(db.Model):
  strings = db.StringListProperty()
```

Then, you can do a query for multiple strings in that list like so:

```
q = Doc.all().filter('strings =', 'str1').filter('strings =', 'str2').get()
```

This will use the merge-join strategy by default, and thus won't require you to build any custom indexes.

Comment: This wont work since my filtering condition doesnot depend on a single property. Thanx for the reply.

Comment: @user617462 Based on how you've described the problem, Nick's solution looks reasonable to me.  If it "won't work" you should explain why in more detail and further clarify your question.

Comment: @user617462 The same approach works if you define separate properties on the doc. In any case, you should search on the doc, rather than creating a 'docjoin'.

Comment: @Robert,@Nick: Your approach works well when I am supposed to query on one or two of the properties of the same kind, but here my problem is that the query properties may not be same. Like I may want to find all those docs with "prop1 as str1" and those with "prop1 as str2 and prop2 as p1" in common. And I dont think this will work in that case. Anyways thanx for your suggestion but it would be good if u could help me even now..

Comment: @user617462 You could use `Doc.all().filter('prop1', 'str1').filter('prop2', 'str2').get()`  There is (currently) no native `OR`, so you'll have to run two queries to get docs with "prop1 = 'str' OR (prop1 = 'xyz' AND prop2 = 'other')".